# jQuery disable previous next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a blogger blog I have two arrow shapes(div with border) with id left1 and right1 for navigation.

I am using jQuery on click to simulate click on 'previous post' and 'newer post'with id prevorig and neworig respectively.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#left1').on('click', function () {
        jQuery('#prevorig')[0].click();
    });
});
```

Previous post has id prevorig and next post has id nextorig.

```
<ul class='pager'>
    <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
        <li class='next'>
            <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' id='neworig' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><data:newerPageTitle/></a>
        </li>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
        <li class='previous'>
            <a class='blog-pager-older-link' id='prevorig' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><data:olderPageTitle/></a>
        </li>
    </b:if>
</ul>
```

However I am not able to hide these two elements with id left1 and right1 when it reaches the latest or the first post. In above case the actual links having id prevorig and neworig are not displayed. How can I do it.
Thanks

Comment: live demo? or fiddle?

Comment: so, if the links in <a> are empty you want to hide them?

Comment: @Frondor in actual demo at www.fumeline.com I am using class selector, I mentioned id here to make my post succint.

Comment: What happens for the latest post, the 'neworig' variable becomes null or empty or any other value?

Comment: neworig is not rendered on webpage then and <ul class ='pager'> has only one child then, prevorig.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
if ($( "#left1" ).length){
    if  ($("#left1").attr('href') == '') { 
     $(this).hide(); 
    }
}
```

Use the same for  blog-pager-older-link

if .hide() is not working due your jquery version try

```
$(this).css('display','none');
```

Comment: yes, i tried it inside. when it is latest post there is no blog-pager-newer-link class.

Comment: At your website when you first enter there is no "newer posts" link...  where exactly want to hide them? and if there is no blog-pager-newer-link class... what other classes does the <a> have?

Comment: it has blog-pager-older-link then. I want to hide elements with id left1 and right1. How can I check if blog-pager-newer-link class exists on webpage or not?

Comment: then just change $(".blog-pager-newer-link") by $("#left1") or right1

Comment: @swapna you can check if blog-pager-newer-link class exists by using this code: `if($('.blog-pager-newer-link').length>0){ //it exists } else{ //it does not exist }`